# QR Code Location Check

Tags: php, html, google-analytics, web, qr-code

I have been told to work out a means of calculating whether a user has accessed a website from scanning a QR code or by accessing through normal methods. The company are using Google Analytics. Ideally the system would calculate what country the user is in when the QR code was scanned, although I think Google analytics does most of this for me.

My initial idea was to have a blank redirect page in the middle of the QR code and the full site, and put some separate analytics code in to that. Alternatively I could perhaps throw in a PHP referrer script that alters the analytics code based on the response, but this would still require a landing redirect page.

I'm a bit of a newbie, and this is quite a big client, so I thought I'd ask on here before starting anything that might not be the best method!

Comment: can you change the qr code/codes?

Comment: nope, unfortunately not.

Comment: so the qr code contains the direct site of you`r client,right?

Comment: ah yes, sorry I can. I just can't have more than one.

Comment: so you can change the qr code info, and it currently holds a url...just to be sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s one good option. Another would be to use a query string parameter in the URL, like this:

```
http://example.com/page/?from=qrcode
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the QR codes, you can add a GET variable to the URL, and then in your index page, you merely test for the QR-code GET variable and {do magic} if it is set or has a certain value.

Answer (score 1):

I would use an intermediate page, as it gives you one point of entry for all QR encoded URLs.

From the QR code:

```
http://yoursite.com/qr.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fyoursite.com%2Ffoo.php
```

Anywhere else:

```
http://yoursite.com/foo.php
```

Then on `qr.php`, you would simply use a `header()` redirect to `$_GET['url']` after you're done with whatever statistics you're going to record or analyze.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you can change the QR code:
    -change the info to something like `www.client-site.com\landing.php?referer=qr`
You can check then in your landing.php

If you can't (then it is messy):
    -when accessing through QR code then the `HTTP_REFERER` is empty and the client is using a phone with a certain browser, you can use this info to determine if he is using a phone and accessed the page directly (90% of cases people use Google before goint directly to a site- in this case you have a `HTTP_REFERER`)
Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

I would build your URL for the QR code using [Google's Analytics URL builder](http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55578).

That way, you don't have to create custom filters are anything. Also, if you ever create new QR codes in the future on any other marketing material, you can track which marketing concept worked easily, rather than just saying that it was just a QR code that brought them to the site. Good luck.